# Ubuntu - How to fix package remove by hand

Tags: boost, apt, ubuntu-22.04

Ubuntu 22

For development purpose I installed libboost 1.74 (apt install) but then to be compatible with a project I installed by hand boost 1.55 in /usr/local. (just the requirements of a project).
Later I noticed some software didn't work like gdb, which couldn't get libboost1.74_regex.

I thought of erasing everything and installing back, so there I am, I have removed (rm) every boost libraries on my system but now how do I force apt (or dpkg) to install libboost1.74. Right now only doc files are getting installed if I
`sudo apt install libboost1.74-all-dev`

All the commands I have tried to remove any trace of libboost to reinstall it later :

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libboost...
sudo apt clean
sudo apt clean all
sudo apt remove --purge libboost...
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt install --fix-missing libboost...
sudo apt update & sudo apt upgrade
```

And also trying to install it with those commands:

```
sudo apt install -f libboost...
sudo apt install --reinstall libboost...
```

I don't really know what else to do.
What I want is a command to tell the package manager to just install libboost without looking at any type of error or what, just get me the libs in /usr/lib.

Before someone tells me about aptitude, you should know it uses boost and therefore won't work before I fix this.

I can still get the boost1.74 and compile it and install it by hand but we are talking about a wm so it will be kinda long to do.

Comment: Better try [ubuntu.se]